Is a check valve required in California and if yes, where?
I realized that the leak indicator of my water meter ever so slightly moves back and forth. This is problematic because I attached a magnetic field sensor to measure the water consumption (and use it for leak detection). But since the disk always slightly moves, it always records a water flow. Furthermore, I find it very concerning that there doesn't seem to be any backflow preventer from my house to the public utility line. It seems I can just push back (possibly contaminated water) into the public utility line! Doesn't feel right to me.
This figure shows the configuration of my water heater (just recently installed):

I made a test and closed the valve (V) that goes to the water heater. Now the meter behaves as expected: The leak indicator does not move any longer and the measured magnetic field stays constant (indicating a quiet nutating disk).
I am not sure about the exact cause but I assume the how water leaks through the mixing valve (M) into the cold water line and causes pressure variations there which pushes my water back into the public utility line.

Did my plumber forget to install a check valve or backflow preventer? Is it required in California?
If not required: Why not? I feel there is high risk that people may inadvertently contaminate the public utility line
Where are the right location(s) for check valve(s) / backflow preventer(s)?


The check valve might be part of the meter and could be defective.

Do you have a pressure gauge on the thermal expansion tank? How do you know what air pressure to set the thermal expansion tank to?

Where does your water line split off to go to outside faucets? In my tract house a 3/4" copper line from the meter at the curb in front goes through the front yard into a box in the ground 3' from the slab foundation. In that box a 1/2" line Tees off to a faucet in front and a 3/4" continues on under the house for all other lines in the house and to one faucet in the back yard. Many people (but not we) have tapped into the 3/4" copper line from the meter to feed an irrigation system. In such cases an added check valve should be placed in the box holding the diversion to the irrigation system.

Not here, it isn't
The California Plumbing Code and its parent Uniform Plumbing Code, as well as the International Plumbing Code, take a point-of-use approach to mandatory backflow prevention, as their goal is to protect not only other water users, but people in the same building as a potential backflow hazard.  As a result, they do not require backflow prevention at the water service entrance, and without anything to check expansion back into the water line, you get the phenomenon you are observing.
The good news is that this backflow situation is essentially harmless since the water put into the water heater was potable to begin with, and generally won't stop becoming potable after being heated.  (If the contents of your hot water heater aren't potable, then you have bigger problems.)  To your concern about pushing contaminated water back into the utility supply, though, the solution is to make sure your points of use are protected properly, including irrigation systems and hose bibbs.

Thanks, I actually called my water company and they do not install any backflow prevention devices. According to them, they require the homeowner to install one in new construction, however.

Now that the meter's leak indicator is very slowly going back and forth (assume the net rotation is zero), do I need to be afraid that the meter adds this as consumption?

@divB the backwards flow cancels out the forward flow, so it won't add as consumption on the meter

Yes you need a check valve.
Do you have a pressure regulating valve?  The check valve is typically installed right after the PRV.
Yes you could push back contaminated water.
I've heard the water meter will register backward flow and count it against you.
Thermal expansion will certainly push water back into the city supply without a check valve.

Not just thermal expansion, but brief changes in mains pressure will cause water to flow into your expansion tank as pressure increases and to flow out of it and back into the mains as the pressure drops. Even with pressure-regulated mains, slight changes in pressure occur as other customers use and stop using water. This is the root cause of the disk moving slightly and continuously -- continuous until you valve off the expansion tank. A check valve will end this behavior of your meter.

I don't think I have a PRV. Just thermal expansion tank as in my diagram. I previously had a tankless water heater, no check valve and never experienced this issue before. Should the water heater installer have installed a check valve? Did he miss it? Was it against code and inspector missed it too? Or is this all independent of the water heater?

I can't find anything in the California Plumbing Code that requires backflow protection at a domestic water service entrance point...

California plumbing code is based on UPC 2021.  602.3 ?  You could argue that any fixture could have a possibility of polluting a water supply given the pipes/fixtures can contain lead or any other prop 52 chemical.

@FreshCodemonger -- UPC 602.3 is just a list of individual fixtures/appliances/water-users that need backflow prevention

My point was that 602.3 pretty much requires backflow prevention on each fixture or you could just do one at the service entrance.  Doesn't seem like much of a choice.
